# How to Load View Controllers At the Beginning of the App?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a Tab View Controller as my root controller in an App which consists of 3 tabs let's call them View A, View B, View C. 
I want to load these tabs as soon as my app starts,  I think it can be done within  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function but I'm not exactly sure, does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of purposes I used this approach:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    rootView = [[SGMenuViewController alloc] init];

    UIViewController *tab1VC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *tab2VC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *tab3VC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *tab4VC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootView];
    UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:tab3VC];

    NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, tab2VC, secondNavController, tab4VC, nil];
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

You basically create a `UITabBarController` and you put all your view there. You create a `UINavigationController` if you need to push/pop views in the selected tab. In the example above only the `1st` and the `3rd` tab have `UINavigationController` and so I can use `self.navigationController pushViewController:` on them.